# Asp Net Core 2.2 project cannot use Class Core Library target 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, class-library

I'm trying to create a custom Asp Net Core Identity Database and i created a class library core, added it as reference on the client project and i cannot find it when i'm trying to use it on the imports...

[image: -cor]

Comment: `Libray` -> `Library`. typo.

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: Does it show up in your solution projects when right clicking depencencies > add refernence? And if you check SDK's for both projects. Are they **exactly** the same?

Comment: only way i could add reference was right click on project > New ITem > Add Reference and SDK are correct

Comment: Does the class library build? Are you sure about the namespace? The namespace is *usually* the same as the project name, but those two things don't have to be the same.

Comment: Yes and Yes, everything looks correct to me, this is why i have no idea what could be